# Exercism Javascript Gigasecond - I do not understand the math

Tags: javascript, ruby, math

Can anyone tell me why in Javascript this is solved by Math.pow(10, 12) or 1000000000000 and not Math.pow(10, 9) or 1000000000. The solution is so clear in ruby and so confusing in JS. My Js solution:

```
var gigDate = Math.pow(10, 12);

function Gigasecond(dateIn) {
  this.dateIn = dateIn
};

Gigasecond.prototype.date = function(){
  return new Date(this.dateIn.getTime() + gigDate);
};  

module.exports = Gigasecond;
```

My ruby code:

```
class Gigasecond
  VERSION = 1
  def self.from(date)
    date + (10**9)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain better... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I had the same question. Thank you for asking this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a bit of reading of the fine manuals would help. In JavaScript, [`getTime` returns *milliseconds*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> **Date.prototype.getTime()**
>   [...]
>   **Return value**
>   A number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

But in Ruby, [`Time#+` expects to see *seconds*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-2B) on the RHS:

> **time + numeric → time**
>   Addition — Adds some number of seconds (possibly fractional) to time and returns that value as a new Time object.

There's your 10<sup>3</sup> difference.

Different languages, different interfaces in the standard libraries, very simple.

Comment: Thank you - I eventually got there but it sure was confusing! Thank you for the help.